# Html how to make news feed avaible to everyone

Tags: html, image, text, feed

I'm creating website in html and would like to create news feeds showing pictures and some text below the pictures.

I would like each user to see the public news feed (from everyone) and only pictures and text posted by that user

I'm trying to write the code for uploading images with text right now.

What form should it be for posting text with images?

Comment: You can't do this only with html

Comment: Yes that would solve the problem

Comment: What should I do with PHP to do news feed? I don't know what should I in PHP, i was only creating with HTML.

Comment: Well, first you have to learn php!

Answer (score 0):

The form will be with 3 elements at least ,  and button. 
To store these things you have to use a server side technology like ASP.NET.